# How to redirect http to https in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am deploying a node js server using

```
npm run start
```

and it works fine.Now I wanted to add the ssl private key so I added the **https_server.js** file below:

```
 var https = require('https');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var https_options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("/home/user/org.key"),
   cert: fs.readFileSync('/home/user/cert.pem')
    };
    https.createServer(https_options , function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("Welcome to Node.js HTTPS Servern");
    }).listen(3000,'0.0.0.0')
```

And then I run

```
 node https_server.js
```

So when i run this it shows "Welcome to Node.js HTTPS Servern" instead of the web application's home page .
Should I change this part

```
res.end("Welcome to Node.js HTTPS Servern");
```

Any help is appreciated .

**EDIT**

I tried also

```
var fs = require('fs');
var net = require('net');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');

var baseAddress = 3000;
var redirectAddress = 3001;
var httpsAddress = 3002;
var httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/home/user/org.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/home/user/cert.pem')
};

net.createServer(tcpConnection).listen(baseAddress);
http.createServer(httpConnection).listen(redirectAddress);
https.createServer(httpsOptions, httpsConnection).listen(httpsAddress);

function tcpConnection(conn) {
    conn.once('data', function (buf) {
        // A TLS handshake record starts with byte 22.
        var address = (buf[0] === 22) ? httpsAddress : redirectAddress;
        var proxy = net.createConnection(address, function () {
            proxy.write(buf);
            conn.pipe(proxy).pipe(conn);
        });
    });
}

function httpConnection(req, res) {
    var host = req.headers['host'];
    res.writeHead(301, { "Location": "https://" + host + req.url });
    res.end();
}

function httpsConnection(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Length': '5' });
    res.end('HTTPS');
}
```

But this one also directs to "HTTPS" not the application's home page

Comment: Hi, are you going to implement SSL using Node JS + Nginx?
You should config Nginx to enable SSL, not update Node JS app.

Comment: If you want to redirect HTTP to HTTPS you actually have to listen for HTTP requests.

Comment: @Brad is it like  my second approach

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I deploy node js app and deploy.

-install nginx on server
-install pm2 on server
-start your node js server using pm2. e.g: localhost:3000
-update nginx config
  o redirect all http requests to https
  o forward https requests to localhost:3000 using proxy_server

nginx configuration:

```
server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name example.com;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 443  ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name  example.com;
        ssl_certificate path_to_certificate;
        ssl_certificate_key path_to_private_key;


        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_read_timeout 5m;
            proxy_connect_timeout 5m;
            proxy_redirect off;

        }
...
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Can we do it without pm2?

Comment: pm2 is used for node js production.

Comment: Do you want to use forever instead of pm2?

Comment: Can we use just nginx without pm2 or forever ?

Comment: Sure, but what do you want to use to start node app?

Answer (score 0):

As @Jikun said you could use nginx as a proxy. Through nginx you can configure your ssl certificates and recieve all requests to 80 port and redirect them to your node server or your error pages. 
It allows you to centralize all requests and serve as an additional layer to avoid direct requests to your server.